# JQUERY - Getting data in a table cell which has a specific class

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have a table such as this below:

```
<table id="Grid">
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Month</th>
     <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>January</td>
     <td class="k-dirty-cell">$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td class="k-dirty-cell">$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>March</td>
     <td>$98</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to iterate (or parse) through cells with class="k-dirty-cell" and get its value and validate whether it is null or not.

The class is always in the second column, so **I am only interested in iterating through the rows of the second column - i.e., when cellIndex = 2.**

I have tried this so far but I'm a bit stuck:

```
$("#Grid tbody").find('td').each(
    function () {
        debugger;

        // run for specific columns - where validation is needed
      //  var isDirty = cellToValidate.hasClass('k-dirty-cell');

       var isDirty = $(this).hasClass('k-dirty-cell');
        if (isDirty == true) {

            var cellContent = $(this).context.innerText;
            var cellIndex = $(this).context.cellIndex;

       //     alert(cellContent + cellIndex);

        }
    });
```

Could you please help if you can.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your primary goal is `I would like to iterate (or parse) through cells with class="k-dirty-cell" and get its value and validate whether it is null or not.`, the following will suffice:

```
$(function() {
  $('td.k-dirty-cell').each(function() {
    var cellValue = $(this).text();
    //do something with cellValue 
    if(cellValue) {
      //not null  
    } else {
      //null
    }
  });
});
```

EDIT: 
since there may be a case where the class is on the first column (per comment discussion), the following will select only second column items with the `k-dirty-cell` class:

```
$(function() {
    $('tr td:nth-child(2).k-dirty-cell').each(function() {
    var cellValue = $(this).text();
      alert(cellValue)
    //do something with cellValue 
    if(cellValue) {
      //not null  
    } else {
      //null
    }
  });
});
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tztLD/

Comment: td.k-dirty-cell, not .td.k-dirty-cell

Comment: @kennypu yes but I only want it to do this check where cellIndex is 2, i.e., the second column in a row. How can I change the above to reflect this?

Comment: @t_plusplus so is there a case when the class is on the first column? if not, there's nothing to change. according to your post, the class is always on the second column, thus there is no need to change anything since it will automatically select the second column only

Comment: @kennypu yes there is such a case actually, but I am only interested in valiating the second column not the first. So even if k-dirty-cell existed in other columns it wont be important to find. thanks.

Comment: @t_plusplus see modified answer

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".k-dirty-cell").each(function() {
    // your code
});
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: you could specify td.k-dirty-cell if you want to make sure they're only td elements that you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to get all the `td` tags whose class is `k-dirty-cell`, so this would be enough:

```
$("#Grid td.k-dirty-cell").each(function() {
    if($(this).text().length > 0) {
       alert("value: " + $(this).text());
     }
}
```